# How to call custom jquery mobile popup when changing page with unsaved data

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

how to call a jQueryMobile popup when clicking on the tab bar icons in single page mobile app - to prevent unsaved data loss

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your questions, but if your clicking on a link to go to an external page, I would pass data through the url and then retrieve it on the second page.

On your first page, this link.  Set var to whatever you want, and set "something" to the variable you want to pass to the next page.

```
<a rel="external" data-ajax="false"  href="page2.html?var1=something">
```

On the second page, use this to retrieve the url variable.

```
  function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars; }

  var something = getUrlVars()["var1"];
```

where the javascript variable "something" is set to whatever url variable you ask for is set to, in this case "var1" from the previous page.

```
alert(var1);
```

You can use alert for testing purposes.  Or setting it with jquery

```
$('#divID').html(var1);
```

and printing it to a div in your body

```
<div id="divID"><!--YOUR DATA WILL PRINT HERE--></div>
```